# Zipping a Mac app bundle with Python

Tags: python, macos, zip, bundle

I'm writing a Python (2.7) script to build and distribute my Mac (10.7) app. I want to zip it up for distribution, but the following code results in an empty zipped app (0 bytes):

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile(zip_file_dist_path, 'w') as dist_zip:
    dist_zip.write(archived_app, os.path.basename(archived_app))
```

Is it treating it as a file, when I need to treat it as a directory? If I zip it up by walking the app bundle's directory tree and writing each file to the zip, will it unzip with all the proper file system metadata (i.e. will I get back out a proper app)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I switched from `ZipFile` to `shutil.make_archive`, since it takes care of the directory recursing, and I don't need any finer-grained control:

```
import shutil

zip_file_path = shutil.make_archive(zip_file_build_path, 'zip', root_dir = dist_dir);
```

Comment: @uchuugaka Couldn't you use the regular `ZipFile` class to unzip?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at all on a Mac .app bundle, loses executable permissions.

Comment: @uchuugaka I'm seeing `shutil.unpack_archive` in the documentation. Does that work for you?

Comment: No it did not. I tried it. What did work was `os.system("unzip -qo sourceFilePath -d  tempDirPath")`  (where the source and destination paths are set up prior in a joined string.

Answer (score 1):

ZipFile only zip one file to an archive once.

You can find how to adding folders to a zip file here:
[Adding folders to a zip file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458436/adding-folders-to-a-zip-file-using-python)