# How do I create a zip file of a file path using Python, including empty directories?

Tags: python, zip, shutil

I've been trying to use the `zipfile` and `shutil.make_archive` modules to recursively create a zip file of a directory.  Both modules work great--except empty directories do not get added to the archive.  Empty directories containing other empty directories are also silently skipped.

I can use 7Zip to create an archive of the same path and empty directories are preserved.  Therefore I know this is possible within the file format itself.  I just don't know how to do it within Python.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: The responsible code is [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8f1a8e80f330/Lib/shutil.py#l452).

Comment: Try adding a dummy file in the directory and deleting that file from the archive after, just to see if zipfile actually supports empty directories (some zip implementations just won't although the format does).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a example using zipfile:

```
import os, zipfile  
from os.path import join  
def zipfolder(foldername, filename, includeEmptyDIr=True):   
    empty_dirs = []  
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)  
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(foldername):  
        empty_dirs.extend([dir for dir in dirs if os.listdir(join(root, dir)) == []])  
        for name in files:  
            zip.write(join(root ,name))  
        if includeEmptyDIr:  
            for dir in empty_dirs:  
                zif = zipfile.ZipInfo(join(root, dir) + "/")  
                zip.writestr(zif, "")  
        empty_dirs = []  
    zip.close() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    zipfolder('test1/noname/', 'zip.zip')
```

Comment: Your code saves the absolute path in the archive.  I modified it slightly to save the relative paths instead (since it will be unzipped on another machine) and it's working great!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: yea, I did that too, but that is easy.
had to backport a project to 2.6, so I had to replace the shutil.make_archive() call.

Comment: Tested under Python 2.7.3 and it doesn't zip the empty dirs, but it does zip everything else. Also the `empty_dirs.extend([dir for dir in dirs if os.listdir(join(root, dir)) == []])` happens way to much - it only needs to be fired off for each root, not every dir in root (because the empty dirs will be walked into)

Comment: I would consider it bad practice to name your ZipFile object ´zip´, as it overwrites the built-in zip-function in python.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to [register a new archive format](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.register_archive_format) to do that, since the default ZIP archiver does not support that. Take a look at [the meat of the existing ZIP archiver](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8f1a8e80f330/Lib/shutil.py#l449). Make your own archiver that creates directories using that currently-unused `dirpath` variable. I looked for how to create an empty directory and found [this](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/19053-add-empty-directory-using-zipfile#edit73291):

```
zip.writestr(zipfile.ZipInfo('empty/'), '')
```

With that, you should be able to write the necessary code to make it archive empty directories.

Answer (score 1):

This is lifted from [Adding folders to a zip file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458436/adding-folders-to-a-zip-file-using-python/792199#792199) but is the only function I have tried that works. The one listed as the answer does not work under Python 2.7.3 (doesn't copy empty directories and is inefficient). The following is tried and tested:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import zipfile

def zipdir(dirPath=None, zipFilePath=None, includeDirInZip=True):

    if not zipFilePath:
        zipFilePath = dirPath + ".zip"
    if not os.path.isdir(dirPath):
        raise OSError("dirPath argument must point to a directory. "
        "'%s' does not." % dirPath)
    parentDir, dirToZip = os.path.split(dirPath)
    #Little nested function to prepare the proper archive path
    def trimPath(path):
        archivePath = path.replace(parentDir, "", 1)
        if parentDir:
            archivePath = archivePath.replace(os.path.sep, "", 1)
        if not includeDirInZip:
            archivePath = archivePath.replace(dirToZip + os.path.sep, "", 1)
        return os.path.normcase(archivePath)

    outFile = zipfile.ZipFile(zipFilePath, "w",
        compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for (archiveDirPath, dirNames, fileNames) in os.walk(dirPath):
        for fileName in fileNames:
            filePath = os.path.join(archiveDirPath, fileName)
            outFile.write(filePath, trimPath(filePath))
        #Make sure we get empty directories as well
        if not fileNames and not dirNames:
            zipInfo = zipfile.ZipInfo(trimPath(archiveDirPath) + "/")
            #some web sites suggest doing
            #zipInfo.external_attr = 16
            #or
            #zipInfo.external_attr = 48
            #Here to allow for inserting an empty directory.  Still TBD/TODO.
            outFile.writestr(zipInfo, "")
    outFile.close()
```

Comment: 16 (or 0x10) is the MS-DOS flag for directories. You should set it, but also the UNIX one too. If you use `ZipInfo.from_path` then it will deal with that for you. Otherwise some programs will unzip you an empty file instead of a directory.

Answer (score -1):

```
def zip_dir(src_dir, dst_zip, *, skip_suffixes=None, dry=False):
    import logging
    from pathlib import Path
    from os import walk
    from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
    from zipfile import ZipFile, ZipInfo

    _log = logging.getLogger(zip_dir.__name__)
    _log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
    _sep = 50 * "-"

    skip_suffixes = skip_suffixes or []
    src_dir, dst_zip = Path(src_dir), Path(dst_zip)
    _log.info("zipping dir: '%s' to: '%s", str(src_dir), str(dst_zip))

    if not src_dir.exists():
        raise FileNotFoundError(str(src_dir))
    if not src_dir.is_dir():
        raise NotADirectoryError(str(src_dir))
    if dst_zip.exists():
        raise FileExistsError(str(dst_zip))

    with TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
        tmp_zip_path = Path(tmp_dir).joinpath(dst_zip.name)

        with ZipFile(str(tmp_zip_path), mode="w") as zip_out:
            for root, dirs, files in walk(src_dir):
                root = Path(root)

                for folder in dirs:
                    folder = root.joinpath(folder)

                    # add empty folders to the zip
                    if not list(folder.iterdir()):
                        _log.debug(_sep)
                        folder_name = f"{str(folder.relative_to(src_dir))}/"
                        _log.debug("empty dir: '%s'", folder_name)

                        if dry:
                            continue

                        zip_out.writestr(ZipInfo(folder_name), "")

                for file in files:
                    file = root.joinpath(file)
                    _log.debug(_sep)
                    _log.debug("adding:  '%s'", str(file))

                    should_skip = None
                    for suffix in file.suffixes:
                        if suffix in skip_suffixes:
                            should_skip = suffix
                            break

                    if should_skip:
                        _log.debug("skipped [%s]: %s", should_skip, str(file))
                        continue

                    arcname = str(file.relative_to(src_dir))
                    _log.debug("arcname: '%s'", arcname)

                    if dry:
                        continue

                    zip_out.write(str(file), arcname=arcname)

        if not dry:
            dst_zip.write_bytes(tmp_zip_path.read_bytes())

        tmp_zip_path.unlink()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s | %(levelname)8s | %(module)25s:%(lineno)-5s | %(message)s")

    zip_dir("/tmp/opera_profile", "opera_profile.zip", skip_suffixes=[".log"], dry=True)
```

Comment: Could you explain what this does and why it's useful?