# adding image to a directory under a zip?

Tags: python, python-2.7, openxml, zip

I want to add an image in a directory under a zip.
The structure of the zip is the following:

**doc1.zip**

```
├── word
|   ├── media
|       ├── img1.png
|       └── img2.png
```

I want to add the picture `soc_logo` under media.
I wrote the following code:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_copy_filename, "w") as documentx:
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename=='word/media/soc_logo.png':
                documentx.write(os.path.join(tmp_dir,filename))
            else:
                documentx.write(os.path.join(tmp_dir,filename), filename)
```

But the result is the following:

**doc1.zip**

```
├── temp
|   ├── /tmpT6kmaW/word/media/
├── word
|   ├── media
|       ├── img1.png
|       └── img2.png
```

Any help please ?

Comment: This seems to be the expected result of the first branch of the `if` statement, which fails to supply an `arcname` parameter and thus writes a file with full pathname (including the temporary directory) into the `ZipFile`. (a) What is the first branch supposed to achieve? (b) Are you sure the `else` branch is ever taken? (c) is the white space between before `.png` intentional?

Comment: Archive names should be relative to the archive root, that is, they should not start with a path separator.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write

Comment: hello, the if is to separate between existed files in the wzip and not existed files, thats mean that word/media/soc_logo.png not existed in the zip. so i should create it. i edited the question and i correct the white space

Comment: This answer should help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/459242/5388440