# How to create a zip archive of a directory?

Tags: python, zip, archive, python-zipfile

How can I create a zip archive of a directory structure in Python?

Comment: Don't use the solution suggested in the accepted answer but the one further down using `make_archive` from `shutil` (if you want to zip a single directory recursively).

Comment: yes, agree with @malana - Martha Yi seems to be unregistered - so is there now way to change the accepted answer through a community process?

Comment: one caveat with `shutil.make_archive` - it doesn't seem to follow symlinks

Comment: The accepted answer is the only one that is actually thread safe in regards to read/write access while creating the zipfile from a directory since each file is opened individually, locking read access to it until the file is closed.

Comment: @Beefcake It says in `make_archive`'s documentation that "_Changed in version 3.10.6_: This function is now made thread-safe during creation of standard `.zip` and tar archives."

Answer (score 718, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you should use [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html). The documentation tells you what functions are available, but doesn't really explain how you can use them to zip an entire directory. I think it's easiest to explain with some example code:

```py
import os
import zipfile
    
def zipdir(path, ziph):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file), 
                       os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), 
                                       os.path.join(path, '..')))

with zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
    zipdir('tmp/', zipf)
```

Comment: I would add a second argument to the write call, passing `os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(path, '..'))`. That would let you zip a directory from any working directory, without getting the full absolute paths in the archive.

Comment: There's a funny recursion going on when I try to zip a folder and output the resultant zip to the same folder. :-)

Comment: `shutil` makes it really easy in just a single line. Please check the answer below..

Comment: you may be more interested by doing ziph.write(os.path.join(path,file), arcname=file) so that the filenames inside the archive are not relative to the hard drive

Comment: I am getting "The compressed (zipped) folder is empty" on Windows 7

Comment: Ah, I was missing the `.close()` call!

Comment: @RoachLord: `file` is not a keyword, even if your editor highlights it as one.

Comment: May also be used with a context manager:

`with zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
    zipdir('tmp/', zipfh)`

Comment: The next answer if more straightforward, and should have been accepted

Comment: What is ````ziph```` in this function? ````path```` is the directory. What if I have a directory containing other sub-directories? I added a question related to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67119676/zip-file-with-different-directories-and-files-python?noredirect=1#comment118642041_67119676

Comment: The next answer does not handle anything related to compression, it just stores the results in a ZIP archive. If you are looking for actual compression, the correct answer is this one and not the next with `shutil`.

Comment: I want to add that this option lets you make a zip archive with any file extension. i.e. `zipfile.ZipFile('Python.meta_zip', 'w')` At my work we have to group a metadata dir with files in it and the file they are associated with together. We don't need compression, we just want to easily have them all in one location when we upload them to the cloud.

Comment: This answer creates a zip containing the directory. How would you change it so that the _contents_ of the directory are added, rather than the directory itself?

Comment: Explaining with examples is the only way to explain properly, thanks :)

Comment: Using the `arcname` parameter of the write function will solve the issue where the entire directory branch is getting zipped rather than just the contents.

Comment: This will not write empty directories to the zip file. To fix this you can also write the `root` in every `os.walk` iteration.

Comment: @Prince and @Shaked do u have an example which accomplish these tasks i.e. writing empty directories and contents of the directory. because i am confused what should we assign to `arcname`

Comment: ok the second argument in `ziph.write` should be modified to `os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), path)` to add the contents of the directory not the entire directory. the only thing remaining is how to write empty directories. @Shaked do u have an example which shows to add empy directories

Comment: @SajjadAli os.mkdir()

Answer (score 2151):

The easiest way is to use [`shutil.make_archive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive). It supports both zip and tar formats.

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive(output_filename, 'zip', dir_name)
```

If you need to do something more complicated than zipping the whole directory (such as skipping certain files), then you'll need to dig into the [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module as others have suggested.

Comment: `shutil` is part of the standard python library. This should be the top answer

Comment: This is the most concise answer here and also has the advantage of adding all subdirectories and files to the archive directly, rather than having everything included in a top-level folder (which results in a redundant level in the folder structure when unzipping).

Comment: @cmcginty could you please be a bit more specific as to what aspect of it is not thread-safe? Will running multiple threads while one calls this cause the interpreter to crash?

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave No, it will not crash. The issue I've seen is that files from different threads will be copied into the same zip file. See https://bugs.python.org/issue30511

Comment: Be warned that prior to Python 3.4, shutil.make_archive does not support ZIP64 and will fail on creating ZIP files larger than 2GB.

Comment: Even though it's not thread-safe, it should still be safe if being used by different threads in different directories, right?

Comment: @Teekin No. If you look at the bugs report (bugs.python.org/issue30511), you'll see that `shutil.make_archive` uses `os.chdir()`. From what I'm reading about `os.chdir()`, it operates globally.

Comment: @azdev, what is the solution for shutil.make_archive for files more than 2GB? I had this error(

Comment: @Jane See the accepted answer or one of the other answers on this page that uses the zipfile library instead of shutil.

Comment: shutil is very, very slow. So, for it is not good option for dirs with large files.

Comment: @azdev For python version 3.6 to 3.7 does shutil work safely for files larger than 2GB?

Comment: If I want to zip a directory instead of the content of directory - is there an option for that? Aslo: can't find what's the equivalent of --remove-files?

Comment: @SwissNavy see `base_dir` option

Comment: I'm trying to automate zipping my work directory which is ~200MB as daily backup, this code kept working and made +84GB and threw an error because my work PC ran out of storage!

Comment: Note this is NOT threadsafe! This does an explicit `os.chdir` which can lead to the wrong directory getting zipped. This led to my zips being gigantic and my disk running out of space.

Comment: for an actual example using both root_dir and base_dir, see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil-archiving-example-with-basedir

Comment: This is not safe,this fails for directories with huge files.

Comment: This answer is not correct. It doesn't compress anything, plus is slower. the accepted answer is correct and should be the reference.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get files referenced by a symlink to copy into the zip archive? When I unzip the created archive a directory for the symlink files is there but the directory is empty.

Comment: can we get to 2023?

Comment: @xjcl Looks like this is thread-safe now for normal use. From the docs: `Changed in version 3.10.6: This function is now made thread-safe during creation of standard .zip and tar archives.`

Answer (score 89):

To add the contents of `mydirectory` to a new zip file, including all files and subdirectories:

```
import os
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile("myzipfile.zip", "w")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("mydirectory"):
    zf.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
zf.close()
```

Comment: For me this code throwing below error    TypeError: invalid file: <zipfile.ZipFile [closed]>

Comment: Can't you use a `with` instead of having to call `close()` yourself at the end?

Comment: example:

`
with zipfile.ZipFile("myzipfile.zip", "w") as zf: pass
`

Comment: This rebuilds the full path to "mydirectory" within the resulting zipfile. i.e. only works as desired if "mydirectory" is in root of your filesystem

Comment: Using the `arcname` parameter of the write function will solve the issue where the entire directory branch is getting zipped rather than just the contents.

Answer (score 65):

> ## How can I create a zip archive of a directory structure in Python?

### In a Python script

In Python 2.7+, `shutil` has a `make_archive` function.

```
from shutil import make_archive
make_archive(
  'zipfile_name', 
  'zip',           # the archive format - or tar, bztar, gztar 
  root_dir=None,   # root for archive - current working dir if None
  base_dir=None)   # start archiving from here - cwd if None too
```

Here the zipped archive will be named `zipfile_name.zip`. If `base_dir` is farther down from `root_dir` it will exclude files not in the `base_dir`, but still archive the files in the parent dirs up to the `root_dir`.

I did have an issue testing this on Cygwin with 2.7 - it wants a root_dir argument, for cwd:

```
make_archive('zipfile_name', 'zip', root_dir='.')
```

### Using Python from the shell

You can do this with Python from the shell also using the `zipfile` module:

```
$ python -m zipfile -c zipname sourcedir
```

Where `zipname` is the name of the destination file you want (add `.zip` if you want it, it won't do it automatically) and sourcedir is the path to the directory.

### Zipping up Python (or just don't want parent dir):

If you're trying to zip up a python package with a `__init__.py` and `__main__.py`, and you don't want the parent dir, it's

```
$ python -m zipfile -c zipname sourcedir/*
```

And

```
$ python zipname
```

would run the package. (Note that you can't run subpackages as the entry point from a zipped archive.)

### Zipping a Python app:

If you have python3.5+, and specifically want to zip up a Python package, use [zipapp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html):

```
$ python -m zipapp myapp
$ python myapp.pyz
```

Answer (score 45):

This function will recursively zip up a directory tree, *compressing* the files, and recording the correct relative filenames in the archive. The archive entries are the same as those generated by `zip -r output.zip source_dir`.

```
import os
import zipfile
def make_zipfile(output_filename, source_dir):
    relroot = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(source_dir, os.pardir))
    with zipfile.ZipFile(output_filename, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
            # add directory (needed for empty dirs)
            zip.write(root, os.path.relpath(root, relroot))
            for file in files:
                filename = os.path.join(root, file)
                if os.path.isfile(filename): # regular files only
                    arcname = os.path.join(os.path.relpath(root, relroot), file)
                    zip.write(filename, arcname)
```

Comment: Sweet, I was wondering if `zipfile` could be used in a `with` statement.
Thanks for pointing out it can.

Answer (score 31):

With python 3.9, `pathlib` & `zipfile` module you can create a zip files from anywhere in the system.

```py
def zip_dir(dir: Union[Path, str], filename: Union[Path, str]):
    """Zip the provided directory without navigating to that directory using `pathlib` module"""

    # Convert to Path object
    dir = Path(dir)

    with zipfile.ZipFile(filename, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_file:
        for entry in dir.rglob("*"):
            zip_file.write(entry, entry.relative_to(dir))
```

It is neat, typed, and has less code.

Answer (score 29):

Modern Python (3.6+) using the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html) module for concise OOP-like handling of paths, and [`pathlib.Path.rglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) for recursive globbing. As far as I can tell, this is equivalent to George V. Reilly's answer: zips with compression, the topmost element is a directory, keeps empty dirs, uses relative paths.

```
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZIP_DEFLATED, ZipFile

from os import PathLike
from typing import Union


def zip_dir(zip_name: str, source_dir: Union[str, PathLike]):
    src_path = Path(source_dir).expanduser().resolve(strict=True)
    with ZipFile(zip_name, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
        for file in src_path.rglob('*'):
            zf.write(file, file.relative_to(src_path.parent))
```

Note: as optional type hints indicate, `zip_name` can't be a Path object ([would be fixed in 3.6.2+](https://bugs.python.org/issue28231)).

Answer (score 28):

Use shutil, which is part of python standard library set. 
Using shutil is so simple(see code below):

- 1st arg: Filename of resultant zip/tar file,
- 2nd arg: zip/tar,
- 3rd arg: dir_name

Code:

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive('/home/user/Desktop/Filename','zip','/home/username/Desktop/Directory')
```

Comment: With all the shutil.make_archvie examples here, they all create empty root folders leading up to the folder that you actually want to archive. I do not want my archive file unarchive with "/home/user/Desktop" so everyone can see where folder of interest was originally. How do i just zip "/Directory" and leave out all traces of parent folders?

Comment: This has been said 3 times already. And it's definitely not the best answer.

Answer (score 13):

For adding compression to the resulting zip file, check out [this link](http://neopatel.blogspot.ca/2010/07/creating-zip-file-in-python-and.html).

You need to change:

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w')
```

to

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Answer (score 7):

I've made some changes to [code given by Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1855118). Below function will also adds empty directories if you have them. Examples should make it more clear what is the path added to the zip.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import zipfile

def addDirToZip(zipHandle, path, basePath=""):
    """
    Adding directory given by \a path to opened zip file \a zipHandle

    @param basePath path that will be removed from \a path when adding to archive

    Examples:
        # add whole "dir" to "test.zip" (when you open "test.zip" you will see only "dir")
        zipHandle = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')
        addDirToZip(zipHandle, 'dir')
        zipHandle.close()

        # add contents of "dir" to "test.zip" (when you open "test.zip" you will see only it's contents)
        zipHandle = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')
        addDirToZip(zipHandle, 'dir', 'dir')
        zipHandle.close()

        # add contents of "dir/subdir" to "test.zip" (when you open "test.zip" you will see only contents of "subdir")
        zipHandle = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')
        addDirToZip(zipHandle, 'dir/subdir', 'dir/subdir')
        zipHandle.close()

        # add whole "dir/subdir" to "test.zip" (when you open "test.zip" you will see only "subdir")
        zipHandle = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')
        addDirToZip(zipHandle, 'dir/subdir', 'dir')
        zipHandle.close()

        # add whole "dir/subdir" with full path to "test.zip" (when you open "test.zip" you will see only "dir" and inside it only "subdir")
        zipHandle = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')
        addDirToZip(zipHandle, 'dir/subdir')
        zipHandle.close()

        # add whole "dir" and "otherDir" (with full path) to "test.zip" (when you open "test.zip" you will see only "dir" and "otherDir")
        zipHandle = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')
        addDirToZip(zipHandle, 'dir')
        addDirToZip(zipHandle, 'otherDir')
        zipHandle.close()
    """
    basePath = basePath.rstrip("\\/") + ""
    basePath = basePath.rstrip("\\/")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        # add dir itself (needed for empty dirs
        zipHandle.write(os.path.join(root, "."))
        # add files
        for file in files:
            filePath = os.path.join(root, file)
            inZipPath = filePath.replace(basePath, "", 1).lstrip("\\/")
            #print filePath + " , " + inZipPath
            zipHandle.write(filePath, inZipPath)
```

Above is a simple function that should work for simple cases. You can find more elegant class in my Gist:
https://gist.github.com/Eccenux/17526123107ca0ac28e6

Comment: The path handling could be greatly simplified by using [os.path](http://doughellmann.com/2008/01/pymotw-os-path.html). See my answer.

Comment: Bug: zipHandle.write(os.path.join(root, ".")) does not take basePath into consideration.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. I've later enhnaced this a bit ;-)
https://gist.github.com/Eccenux/17526123107ca0ac28e6

Answer (score 6):

To retain the folder hierarchy under the parent directory to be archived:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import zipfile

fp_zip = Path("output.zip")
path_to_archive = Path("./path-to-archive")

with zipfile.ZipFile(fp_zip, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
    for fp in path_to_archive.glob("**/*"):
        zipf.write(fp, arcname=fp.relative_to(path_to_archive))
```

Answer (score 4):

I have another code example that may help, using python3, pathlib and zipfile.
It should work in any OS.

```
from pathlib import Path
import zipfile
from datetime import datetime

DATE_FORMAT = '%y%m%d'


def date_str():
    """returns the today string year, month, day"""
    return '{}'.format(datetime.now().strftime(DATE_FORMAT))


def zip_name(path):
    """returns the zip filename as string"""
    cur_dir = Path(path).resolve()
    parent_dir = cur_dir.parents[0]
    zip_filename = '{}/{}_{}.zip'.format(parent_dir, cur_dir.name, date_str())
    p_zip = Path(zip_filename)
    n = 1
    while p_zip.exists():
        zip_filename = ('{}/{}_{}_{}.zip'.format(parent_dir, cur_dir.name,
                                             date_str(), n))
        p_zip = Path(zip_filename)
        n += 1
    return zip_filename


def all_files(path):
    """iterator returns all files and folders from path as absolute path string
    """
    for child in Path(path).iterdir():
        yield str(child)
        if child.is_dir():
            for grand_child in all_files(str(child)):
                yield str(Path(grand_child))


def zip_dir(path):
    """generate a zip"""
    zip_filename = zip_name(path)
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'w')
    print('create:', zip_filename)
    for file in all_files(path):
        print('adding... ', file)
        zip_file.write(file)
    zip_file.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    zip_dir('.')
    print('end!')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a functionality like the compress folder of any common graphical file manager you can use the following code, it uses the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) module. Using this code you will have the zip file with the path as its root folder.

```
import os
import zipfile

def zipdir(path, ziph):
    # Iterate all the directories and files
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        # Create a prefix variable with the folder structure inside the path folder. 
        # So if a file is at the path directory will be at the root directory of the zip file
        # so the prefix will be empty. If the file belongs to a containing folder of path folder 
        # then the prefix will be that folder.
        if root.replace(path,'') == '':
                prefix = ''
        else:
                # Keep the folder structure after the path folder, append a '/' at the end 
                # and remome the first character, if it is a '/' in order to have a path like 
                # folder1/folder2/file.txt
                prefix = root.replace(path, '') + '/'
                if (prefix[0] == '/'):
                        prefix = prefix[1:]
        for filename in files:
                actual_file_path = root + '/' + filename
                zipped_file_path = prefix + filename
                zipf.write( actual_file_path, zipped_file_path)


zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zipdir('/tmp/justtest/', zipf)
zipf.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

So many answers here, and I hope I might contribute with my own version, which is based on the original answer (by the way), but with a more graphical perspective, also using context for each `zipfile` setup and sorting `os.walk()`, in order to have a ordered output.

Having these folders and them files (among other folders), I wanted to create a `.zip` for each `cap_` folder:

```
$ tree -d
.
├── cap_01
|    ├── 0101000001.json
|    ├── 0101000002.json
|    ├── 0101000003.json
|
├── cap_02
|    ├── 0201000001.json
|    ├── 0201000002.json
|    ├── 0201001003.json
|
├── cap_03
|    ├── 0301000001.json
|    ├── 0301000002.json
|    ├── 0301000003.json
| 
├── docs
|    ├── map.txt
|    ├── main_data.xml
|
├── core_files
     ├── core_master
     ├── core_slave
```

Here's what I applied, with comments for better understanding of the process.

```
$ cat zip_cap_dirs.py 
""" Zip 'cap_*' directories. """           
import os                                                                       
import zipfile as zf                                                            


for root, dirs, files in sorted(os.walk('.')):                                                                                               
    if 'cap_' in root:                                                          
        print(f"Compressing: {root}")                                           
        # Defining .zip name, according to Capítulo.                            
        cap_dir_zip = '{}.zip'.format(root)                                     
        # Opening zipfile context for current root dir.                         
        with zf.ZipFile(cap_dir_zip, 'w', zf.ZIP_DEFLATED) as new_zip:          
            # Iterating over os.walk list of files for the current root dir.    
            for f in files:                                                     
                # Defining relative path to files from current root dir.        
                f_path = os.path.join(root, f)                                  
                # Writing the file on the .zip file of the context              
                new_zip.write(f_path)
```

Basically, for each iteration over `os.walk(path)`, I'm opening a context for `zipfile` setup and afterwards, iterating iterating over `files`, which is a `list` of files from `root` directory, forming the relative path for each file based on the current `root` directory, appending to the `zipfile` context which is running.

And the output is presented like this:

```
$ python3 zip_cap_dirs.py
Compressing: ./cap_01
Compressing: ./cap_02
Compressing: ./cap_03
```

To see the contents of each `.zip` directory, you can use `less` command:

```
$ less cap_01.zip

Archive:  cap_01.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
  22017  Defl:N     2471  89% 2019-09-05 08:05 7a3b5ec6  cap_01/0101000001.json
  21998  Defl:N     2471  89% 2019-09-05 08:05 155bece7  cap_01/0101000002.json
  23236  Defl:N     2573  89% 2019-09-05 08:05 55fced20  cap_01/0101000003.json
--------          ------- ---                           -------
  67251             7515  89%                            3 files
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `pathlib.Path`, which is independent of the OS used:

```py
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path

def zip_dir(path: Path, zip_file_path: Path):
    """Zip all contents of path to zip_file"""
    files_to_zip = [
        file for file in path.glob('*') if file.is_file()]
    with zipfile.ZipFile(
        zip_file_path, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_f:
        for file in files_to_zip:
            print(file.name)
            zip_f.write(file, file.name)

current_dir = Path.cwd()  
tozip_dir = current_dir / "test"
zip_dir(
    tozip_dir, current_dir / 'dir.zip')
```

Answer (score 2):

To give more flexibility, e.g. select directory/file by name use:

```
import os
import zipfile

def zipall(ob, path, rel=""):
    basename = os.path.basename(path)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        if rel == "":
            rel = basename
        ob.write(path, os.path.join(rel))
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for d in dirs:
                zipall(ob, os.path.join(root, d), os.path.join(rel, d))
            for f in files:
                ob.write(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(rel, f))
            break
    elif os.path.isfile(path):
        ob.write(path, os.path.join(rel, basename))
    else:
        pass
```

For a file tree:

```
.
├── dir
│   ├── dir2
│   │   └── file2.txt
│   ├── dir3
│   │   └── file3.txt
│   └── file.txt
├── dir4
│   ├── dir5
│   └── file4.txt
├── listdir.zip
├── main.py
├── root.txt
└── selective.zip
```

You can e.g. select only `dir4` and `root.txt`:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
files = [os.path.join(cwd, f) for f in ['dir4', 'root.txt']]

with zipfile.ZipFile("selective.zip", "w" ) as myzip:
    for f in files:
        zipall(myzip, f)
```

Or just `listdir` in script invocation directory and add everything from there:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("listdir.zip", "w" ) as myzip:
    for f in os.listdir():
        if f == "listdir.zip":
            # Creating a listdir.zip in the same directory
            # will include listdir.zip inside itself, beware of this
            continue
        zipall(myzip, f)
```

Comment: This zips, but doesn't compress.

Answer (score 2):

While using `shutil` note that you should include output directory path in `base_name` arg:

```
import shutil


shutil.make_archive(
  base_name=output_dir_path + output_filename_without_extension, 
  format="zip", 
  root_dir=input_root_dir)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at the `zipfile` module; there's documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html.

You may also want `os.walk()` to index the directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation on the answer given by Nux that works for me:

```
def WriteDirectoryToZipFile( zipHandle, srcPath, zipLocalPath = "", zipOperation = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED ):
    basePath = os.path.split( srcPath )[ 0 ]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk( srcPath ):
        p = os.path.join( zipLocalPath, root [ ( len( basePath ) + 1 ) : ] )
        # add dir
        zipHandle.write( root, p, zipOperation )
        # add files
        for f in files:
            filePath = os.path.join( root, f )
            fileInZipPath = os.path.join( p, f )
            zipHandle.write( filePath, fileInZipPath, zipOperation )
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try the below one .it worked for me**.

```
import zipfile, os
zipf = "compress.zip"  
def main():
    directory = r"Filepath"
    toZip(directory)
def toZip(directory):
    zippedHelp = zipfile.ZipFile(zipf, "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED )

    list = os.listdir(directory)
    for file_list in list:
        file_name = os.path.join(directory,file_list)

        if os.path.isfile(file_name):
            print file_name
            zippedHelp.write(file_name)
        else:
            addFolderToZip(zippedHelp,file_list,directory)
            print "---------------Directory Found-----------------------"
    zippedHelp.close()

def addFolderToZip(zippedHelp,folder,directory):
    path=os.path.join(directory,folder)
    print path
    file_list=os.listdir(path)
    for file_name in file_list:
        file_path=os.path.join(path,file_name)
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            zippedHelp.write(file_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(file_name):
            print "------------------sub directory found--------------------"
            addFolderToZip(zippedHelp,file_name,path)


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to Zip all the folders(sub directories) in the current directory.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for sub_dir in dirs:
        zip_you_want = sub_dir+".zip"
        zip_process = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_you_want, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        zip_process.write(file_you_want_to_include)
        zip_process.close()

        print("Successfully zipped directory: {sub_dir}".format(sub_dir=sub_dir))
```

Answer (score 1):

Zip a file or a tree (a directory and its sub-directories).

```
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED

def make_zip(tree_path, zip_path, mode='w', skip_empty_dir=False):
    with ZipFile(zip_path, mode=mode, compression=ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
        paths = [Path(tree_path)]
        while paths:
            p = paths.pop()
            if p.is_dir():
                paths.extend(p.iterdir())
                if skip_empty_dir:
                    continue
            zf.write(p)
```

To append to an existing archive, pass `mode='a'`, to create a fresh archive `mode='w'` (the default in the above). So let's say you want to bundle 3 different directory trees under the same archive.

```
make_zip(path_to_tree1, path_to_arch, mode='w')
make_zip(path_to_tree2, path_to_arch, mode='a')
make_zip(path_to_file3, path_to_arch, mode='a')
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way to go would be to go with shutil, Like the second top answer says so, But if you still wish to go with ZipFile for some reason, And if you are getting some trouble doing that (Like ERR 13 in Windows etc), You can use this fix:

```
import os
import zipfile

def retrieve_file_paths(dirName):
  filePaths = []
  for root, directories, files in os.walk(dirName):
    for filename in files:
        filePath = os.path.join(root, filename)
        filePaths.append(filePath)
  return filePaths
 
def main(dir_name, output_filename):
  filePaths = retrieve_file_paths(dir_name)
   
  zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(output_filename+'.zip', 'w')
  with zip_file:
    for file in filePaths:
      zip_file.write(file)

main("my_dir", "my_dir_archived")
```

This one recursively iterates through every sub-folder/file in your given folder, And writes them to a zip file instead of attempting to directly zip a folder.

Answer (score 1):

One thing completely missed by previous answers is the fact that using `os.path.join()` can easily return POSIX-incompatible paths when you run the code on Windows. The resulting archive will contain files with literal backslashes in their names when processing it with any common archive software on Linux, which is not what you want. Use `path.as_posix()` for the `arcname` parameter instead!

```py
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path
with zipfile.ZipFile("archive.zip", "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    for path in Path("include_all_of_this_folder").rglob("*"):
        zf.write(path, path.as_posix())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modern approach, using pathlib, and a context manager. Puts the files directly in the zip, rather than in a subfolder.

```
def zip_dir(filename: str, dir_to_zip: pathlib.Path):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
        # Use glob instead of iterdir(), to cover all subdirectories.
        for directory in dir_to_zip.glob('**'):
            for file in directory.iterdir():
                if not file.is_file():
                    continue
                # Strip the first component, so we don't create an uneeded subdirectory
                # containing everything.
                zip_path = pathlib.Path(*file.parts[1:])
                # Use a string, since zipfile doesn't support pathlib  directly.
                zipf.write(str(file), str(zip_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a function by consolidating Mark Byers' solution with Reimund and Morten Zilmer's comments (relative path and including empty directories). As a best practice, `with` is used in ZipFile's file construction.

The function also prepares a default zip file name with the zipped directory name and '.zip' extension. Therefore, it works with only one argument: the source directory to be zipped.

```
import os
import zipfile

def zip_dir(path_dir, path_file_zip=''):
if not path_file_zip:
    path_file_zip = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(path_dir), os.path.basename(path_dir)+'.zip')
with zipfile.ZipFile(path_file_zip, 'wb', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_file:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_dir):
        for file_or_dir in files + dirs:
            zip_file.write(
                os.path.join(root, file_or_dir),
                os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file_or_dir),
                                os.path.join(path_dir, os.path.pardir)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# import required python modules
# You have to install zipfile package using pip install

import os,zipfile

# Change the directory where you want your new zip file to be

os.chdir('Type your destination')

# Create a new zipfile ( I called it myfile )

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('myfile.zip','w')

# os.walk gives a directory tree. Access the files using a for loop

for dirnames,folders,files in os.walk('Type your directory'):
    zf.write('Type your Directory')
    for file in files:
        zf.write(os.path.join('Type your directory',file))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after reading the suggestions I came up with a very similar way that works with 2.7.x without creating "funny" directory names (absolute-like names), and will only create the specified folder inside the zip.

Or just in case you needed your zip to contain a folder inside with the contents of the selected directory.

```
def zipDir( path, ziph ) :
 """
 Inserts directory (path) into zipfile instance (ziph)
 """
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk( path ) :
  for file in files :
   ziph.write( os.path.join( root, file ) , os.path.basename( os.path.normpath( path ) ) + "\\" + file )

def makeZip( pathToFolder ) :
 """
 Creates a zip file with the specified folder
 """
 zipf = zipfile.ZipFile( pathToFolder + 'file.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED )
 zipDir( pathToFolder, zipf )
 zipf.close()
 print( "Zip file saved to: " + pathToFolder)

makeZip( "c:\\path\\to\\folder\\to\\insert\\into\\zipfile" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Function to create zip file.

```
def CREATEZIPFILE(zipname, path):
    #function to create a zip file
    #Parameters: zipname - name of the zip file; path - name of folder/file to be put in zip file

    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zipf.setpassword(b"password") #if you want to set password to zipfile

    #checks if the path is file or directory
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        for files in os.listdir(path):
            zipf.write(os.path.join(path, files), files)

    elif os.path.isfile(path):
        zipf.write(os.path.join(path), path)
    zipf.close()
```

Comment: please explain with an example so that i can correct my answer

Comment: However, zipfile "currently cannot create an encrypted file" (from https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zipfile.html)

Answer (score 0):

summary others, make a function:

```py
import zipfile

def zipFolder(toZipFolder, outputZipFile):
  """
    zip/compress a whole folder/directory to zip file
  """
  print("Zip for foler %s" % toZipFolder)
  with zipfile.ZipFile(outputZipFile, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipFp:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(toZipFolder):
      # print("%s" % ("-"*80))
      # print("dirpath=%s, dirnames=%s, filenames=%s" % (dirpath, dirnames, filenames))
      # print("Folder: %s, Files: %s" % (dirpath, filenames))
      for curFileName in filenames:
        # print("curFileName=%s" % curFileName)
        curFilePath = os.path.join(dirpath, curFileName)
        # print("curFilePath=%s" % curFilePath)
        fileRelativePath = os.path.relpath(curFilePath, toZipFolder)
        # print("fileRelativePath=%s" % fileRelativePath)
        # print("  %s" % fileRelativePath)
        zipFp.write(curFilePath, arcname=fileRelativePath)
  print("Completed zip file %s" % outputZipFile)
```

call:

```py
  toZipFullPath = "/Users/crifan/dev/dev_root/iosReverse/WhatsApp/ipa/forRepackIpa_20231128"
  outputZipFile = "/Users/crifan/dev/dev_root/iosReverse/WhatsApp/ipa/WhatsApp_v23.24.0_20231128.ipa"
  zipFolder(toZipFullPath, outputZipFile)
```

output:

```
Zip for foler /Users/crifan/dev/dev_root/iosReverse/WhatsApp/ipa/forRepackIpa_20231128
Completed zip file /Users/crifan/dev/dev_root/iosReverse/WhatsApp/ipa/WhatsApp_v23.20.79_idaAllSymbols_20231128.ipa
```

latest code: [crifanLib/crifanFile.py](https://github.com/crifan/crifanLibPython/blob/master/python3/crifanLib/crifanFile.py)