# Python - Writing a folder and its contents to a ZipFile

Tags: python, copy, zip, directory

Is it possible to write a folder and its contents to an existing ZipFile? 
I've been messing around with this for a while and can only manage to write the folder structure to the archive, anything inside the folder isn't copied. 
I don't want to point to a specific file, because the idea is that the folder contents can change and the program will just copy the whole folder into the archive no matter what is inside.

Currently I have,

```
myzipfile.write('A Folder\\Another Folder\\')
```

but I want the contents of 'Another Folder' to be copied as well not just the empty folder

Hopefully you understand what I mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a zip archive of a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os
for dirpath,dirs,files in os.walk('A Folder/Another folder'):
  for f in files:
    fn = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
    myzipfile.write(fn)
```