# Create .zip in Python?

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

I'm trying to create a function in my script that zips the contents of a given source directory (`src`) to a zip file (`dst`). For example, `zip('/path/to/dir', '/path/to/file.zip')`, where `/path/to/dir` is a directory, and `/path/to/file.zip` doesn't exist yet. I **do not** want to zip the directory itself, this makes all the difference in my case. I want to zip the files (and subdirs) in the directory. This is what I'm trying:

```
def zip(src, dst):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile("%s.zip" % (dst), "w")
    for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
        zf.write(dirname)
        for filename in files:
            zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
    zf.close()
```

This creates a zip that is essentially `/`. For example, if I zipped `/path/to/dir`, extracting the zip creates a directory with "path" in it, with "to" in that directory, etc.

Does anyone have a function that doesn't cause this problem?

I can't stress this enough, it **needs** to zip the files in the directory, not the directoy itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a zip archive of a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The [`zipfile.write()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.write) method takes an optional `arcname` argument
that specifies what the name of the file should be inside the zipfile.

You can use this to strip off the path to `src` at the beginning. Here I
use [`os.path.abspath()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) to make sure that both `src` and the
filename returned by `os.walk()` have a common prefix.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os
import zipfile

def zip(src, dst):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile("%s.zip" % (dst), "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    abs_src = os.path.abspath(src)
    for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for filename in files:
            absname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
            arcname = absname[len(abs_src) + 1:]
            print 'zipping %s as %s' % (os.path.join(dirname, filename),
                                        arcname)
            zf.write(absname, arcname)
    zf.close()

zip("src", "dst")
```

With a directory structure like this:

```
src
└── a
    ├── b
    │   └── bar
    └── foo
```

The script prints:

```
zipping src/a/foo as a/foo
zipping src/a/b/bar as a/b/bar
```

And the contents of the resulting zip file are:

```
Archive:  dst.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  01-28-13 11:36   a/foo
        0  01-28-13 11:36   a/b/bar
 --------                   -------
        0                   2 files
```

Comment: Looks promising (EDIT: works perfectly), but is there any reason to import `os` and `os.path`?

Comment: Yes—`os` for `os.walk()`, and `os.path` for `os.path.abspath()` and `os.path.join()`.

Comment: @andrew you have access to `os.path` without importing it separately.  The main reason to do this is if you rename it like `import os.path as P` or whatever.

Comment: @agoebel also, while we're at it, what's the difference between `import os.path` and `from os import path`

Comment: @tkbx: `from os import path` puts `path` at the top level, so you can do `path.join` instead of `os.path.join`. This is usually not what you want to do (especially since everyone always has a variable named `path` somewhere in their code).

Comment: @tkbx Huh, for some reason I thought I needed to import `os.path` separately, but you’re quite right, I don’t need to. That will save at least a line on most scripts I write in the future—thanks!

Comment: @abarnert that's why it's `script, vars = argv` when you `from sys import argv`. So, could you instead do `import sys.argv` and `script, vars = sys.argv`?

Comment: @tkbx: No, you can't `import sys.argv` unless `argv` is a sub-module under `sys`. But `argv` isn't a module, it's just a `list`. But when you `import sys`—which is the normal thing you do most of the time—you then do `script, vars = sys.argv`. (Although really, you wouldn't write _that_ very often, either, because you'll get a `ValueError` if there are 0 or 2 command-line arguments.)

Comment: @tkbx: Read [More on Modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules) from the tutorial.

Comment: This function works fine, but it will not add empty folder into the zip file, which in most case is the expected behavior. In another word, any sub-folder without a file in it will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you are close.  You could use `dirname` and `basename` to make sure you are grabbing the right path name:

```
>>> os.path.dirname("/path/to/dst")
'/path/to'
>>> os.path.basename("/path/to/dst")
'dst'
```

Then using `chdir` you can make sure you are in the parent so the paths are relative.

```
def zip(src, dst):
    parent = os.path.dirname(dst)
    folder = os.path.basename(dst)

    os.chdir(parent):
    for dirname, subdirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
        ...
```

This creates:

```
dst/a.txt
dst/b
dst/b/c.txt
...etc...
```

If do not want to include the name "dst" you can just do `os.chdir(dst)` and then `os.walk('.')`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please note that `zip` is also a builtin function with very different purpose: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`arcname` parameter](http://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) to control the name/path in the zip file.

For example, for a zip file that contains only files, no directories:

```
zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename), arcname=filename)
```

Or to invent a new directory inside the zip file:

```
zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename), arcname=os.path.join("my_zip_dir", filename))
```