# How to create a zip file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I want to create a file .zip in python that includes an entire folder + another file,how can i make it?

```
files.zip:
 |-mydir
 |-file.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: You tagged zipfile so I assume you are familiar with the python module zipfile: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html Have you tried it out? Can you share some code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create .zip in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568647/create-zip-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
In according with [zip documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects)

```
with ZipFile('Your_zip_file.zip','w') as zip:
    # writing each file one by one
    for file in os.listdir(str(Path("folder_to_zip/"))):
        zip.write('folder_to_zip/'+str(file))
    zip.close()
```

Use:

- 'r' to read an existing file,
- 'w' to truncate and write a new file,
- 'a' to append to an existing file, or
- 'x' to exclusively create and write a new file.

Hope this will be helpful for others.