# zip a file in python

Tags: python, zip

I'm trying to zip a file in python, my code is:

```
import zipfile
f = zipfile.ZipFile('/home/tom/Desktop/test.csv.zip','w',zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
f.write('/home/tom/Desktop/test.csv')
f.close()
```

It's working well, but inside my zip file I'm having the full path: /home/tom/Desktop/test.csv

How can I just get test.csv inside the zip file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a zip archive of a directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write):

> `ZipFile.write(filename[, arcname[, compress_type]])`
>
> Write the file named *filename* to the archive, giving it the archive name *arcname* (by default, this will be the same as filename, but without a drive letter and with leading path separators removed).

So...

```
f.write('/home/tom/Desktop/test.csv', 'test.csv')
```