# Python zipfile whole path is in file

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I'm using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory) to make a zip file from a directory. I give the function an absolute path to a folder from a GUI. Currently, say the path is c:\users......, the zip folder structure is users...... .

How can I remove the absolute path bits and just have the end folder of the path being used for the zip file? I understand that the result is right, because what I'm describing is the result from os.walk but I want to strip out the absolute path.

```
def zipdir(path, zip):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            zip.write(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
def zipdir(path, zip):
    path = os.path.abspath(path)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        dest_dir = root.replace(os.path.dirname(path), '', 1)
        for file in files:
            zip.write(os.path.join(root, file), arcname=os.path.join(dest_dir, file))
```

This converts the given `path` to an absolute path, the directory name of which is used to remove the leading path component in `root`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to preserve the file structure. I essentially want to pass an absolute path for the directory and the program to just make a zip file exactly the same as the contents of that directory, with nothing else. Is that possible?

Comment: @user2290362 - yes, that's the bit that was unclear. See updated answer.