# How to compress a processed text file in Python?

Tags: python, compression

I have a text file which I constantly append data to. When processing is done I need to gzip the file. I tried several options like `shutil.make_archive`, `tarfile`, `gzip` but could not eventually do it. Is there no simple way to compress a file without actually writing to it?

Let's say I have **mydata.txt** file and I want it to be gzipped and saved as **mydata.txt.gz**.

Comment: What do you mean "without writing to it"? If you don't write to the compressed file, `mydata.txt.gz` is going to be empty.

Comment: What does "could not eventually do it" even mean? What did you try *exactly*, and what error(s) did you get? Show some code!

Comment: @abarnert I have a processed file called `mydata.txt` it already contains data, isn't it? Next step, I need to compress it. If I do it the way it is shown in examples with 'w' parameter the file gonna be overwritten and empty so this is what "without actually writing to it" means. I tried 'a:gz' parameter of `tarfile` but it does not accept it.

Comment: See [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) with [`hook_compressed`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.hook_compressed)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the problem. You should be able to use e.g. the [gzip module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) just fine, something like this:

```
inf = open("mydata.txt", "rb")
outf = gzip.open("file.txt.gz", "wb")
outf.write(inf.read())
outf.close()
inf.close()
```

There's no problem with the file being overwritten, the name given to `gzip.open()` is completely independent of the name given to plain `open()`.

Comment: Indeed, I thought it will be slow, but it appears not critically.

Comment: @minerals: Why would it be slow? If you're worried about reading the whole file into memory, you can just loop over 8K at a time instead of the whole file at once; it doesn't change anything essential.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compress a file without writing to it, you could run a shell command such as `gzip` using the Python libraries `subprocess` or `popen` or `os.system`.

Comment: I could but I'd rather not use subprocess.

Comment: @minerals why not use `subprocess`?

Comment: I don't see how this helps anything. `gzip` is going to end up writing to the same file he'd write to himself. (Or, if it doesn't, it's going to end up not doing what he wants.)