# Write data to Redis from PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In Scala, we would write an RDD to Redis like this:

```
datardd.foreachPartition(iter => {
      val r = new RedisClient("hosturl", 6379)
      iter.foreach(i => {
        val (str, it) = i
        val map = it.toMap
        r.hmset(str, map)
      })
    })
```

I tried doing this in PySpark like this: `datardd.foreachPartition(storeToRedis)`, where function `storeToRedis` is defined as:

```
def storeToRedis(x):
    r = redis.StrictRedis(host = 'hosturl', port = 6379)
    for i in x:
        r.set(i[0], dict(i[1]))
```

It gives me this:

> ImportError: ('No module named redis', function subimport at
>   0x47879b0, ('redis',))

Of course, I have imported redis.

Comment: Is `redis` installed on every worker?

Comment: @zero323 Is that the way to do it? Install `redis` on every worker.

Comment: python modules to be used in the workers must be on all the workers....  so he means the python redis module, not a redis db installation.

Comment: @Paul: I understood what he meant, and that's what I am asking. Do I have to install the python redis module on all the workers manually? There should be an easier and shortcut way, like Scala API's `addJars` method.

Comment: @kamalbanga I'm unaware of a good way.  Of course you could try to use spark to make the workers run `pip` or `easy_install` but unless you can limit workers to one per machine, it might not behave very well.

Comment: @Paul Doesn't PySpark API's `addPyFile` do this thing?

Comment: @kamalbanga Yes, sort of.  I think addPyFile is best for short project oriented modules, not big distributions like, say, scipy.  Searching for "scipy not on spark cluster" led to [this from databricks](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/1294/no-module-named-numpy-on-spark-cluster-on-ec2.html) where they suggest install scipy locally and copying the directory to all the workers using a script included in spark.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for this link.

Comment: @kamalbanga Personally I would recommend Ansible but it is probably a matter of taste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PySpark's SparkContext has a `addPyFile` method specifically for this thing. 
Make the redis module a zip file ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25650295/2436425)) and just call this method:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName = "analyze")
sc.addPyFile("/path/to/redis.zip")
```