# Redis and Pyspark configuration

Tags: apache-spark, redis, pyspark

We have one EC2 test VM with spark master and 3 spark workers, what configs need to be done for Redis to work with PySpark? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make a zip file of Redis Module 
2) Use PySpark's addPyFile as below 
sc.addPyFile("/path/to/redis.zip")

Reference : [Write data to Redis from PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274540/write-data-to-redis-from-pyspark)