# How to zip or tar a static folder without writing anything to the filesystem in python?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, archive, webapp2

I know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1855095/2284570). But you can’t write to filesystem in app engine *(shutil or zipfile require creating files)*.

So basically I need to archive something like`/base/nacl`using zip or tar, and write the output to the web browser asking the page *(the output will never exceed 32 Mb)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just happened that I had to solve the exact same problem tonight :) This worked for me:

```
    import StringIO
    import tarfile

    fd = StringIO.StringIO()

    with tarfile.open(mode="w:gz", fileobj=fd) as tgz:
        tgz.add('dir_to_download')

    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] ='application/octet-stream'
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="archive.tgz"'

    self.response.write(fd.getvalue())
```

Key points:

- used `StringIO` to fake a file in memory
- used `fileobj` to pass directly the fake file's object to `tarfile.open()` (also supported by `gzip.GzipFile()` if you prefer `gzip` instead of `tarfile`)
- set headers to present the response as a downloadable file