# How to use paralledots api in app engine?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, webapp2, semantic-analysis

I want to check text similarity using paralleldots api in app engine, but when setting the api key in app engine using.

```
paralleldots.set_api_key("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

App engine giving Error:

```
    with open('settings.cfg', 'w') as configfile:
  File "/home/ulti72/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/stubs.py", line 278, in __init__
    raise IOError(errno.EROFS, 'Read-only file system', filename)
IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'settings.cfg'
INFO     2019-03-17 10:43:59,852 module.py:835] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2019-03-17 10:46:47,548 client.py:777] Refreshing access_token
ERROR    2019-03-17 10:46:50,931 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ulti72/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/ulti72/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/ulti72/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/ulti72/Desktop/koda/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    paralleldots.set_api_key("7PR8iwo42DGFB8qpLjpUGJPqEQHU322lqTDkgaMrX7I")
  File "/home/ulti72/Desktop/koda/lib/paralleldots/config.py", line 13, in set_api_key
    with open('settings.cfg', 'w') as configfile:
  File "/home/ulti72/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/stubs.py", line 278, in __init__
    raise IOError(errno.EROFS, 'Read-only file system', filename)
IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'settings.cfg'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `paralleldots` api, seems to want to save a `settings.cfg` file to the local filesystem in response to that call. Which is not allowed [in the 1st generation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#Python_The_sandbox) standard environment and only allowed for files in the `/tmp` filesystem [in the 2nd generation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#filesystem).

The local development server was designed for the 1st generation standard env and enforces the restriction with that error. It has limited support for the 2nd generation env, see [Python 3.7 Local Development Server Options for new app engine apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999747/python-3-7-local-development-server-options-for-new-app-engine-apps/53000831#53000831).

Things to try:

- check if specifying the location of the `settings.cfg` is supported and if so make it reside under `/tmp`. *Maybe* the local development server allows that or you switch to some other local development method than the development server.
- check if saving the settings using an already open file handler is supported and, if so, use one obtained from Cloud Storage client library, something along these lines: [How to zip or tar a static folder without writing anything to the filesystem in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38885764/how-to-zip-or-tar-a-static-folder-without-writing-anything-to-the-filesystem-in/38888667#38888667)
- check if `set_api_key()` supports some other method of persisting the API key than saving the settings to a file
- check if it's possible to specify the API key for every subsequent call so you don't have to persist it using `set_api_key()` (maybe using a common wrapper function for convenience)