# Is shutil.make_archive thread safe?

Tags: python, archive, shutil

I am trying to zip multiple folders using `shutil.make_archive` using threads in python. I see that the smaller folder zips completely and at the same time the other thread also stops zipping.

So, is `shutil.make_archive` thread safe?

Answer (score 5):

`shutil.make_archive()` is **not** thread-safe.

The reason for it is that it changes the current working directory, which is global for the process. Threads don't have their own working directory. See the relevant code in Python 2.7:

```
save_cwd = os.getcwd()
if root_dir is not None:
    if logger is not None:
        logger.debug("changing into '%s'", root_dir)
    base_name = os.path.abspath(base_name)
    if not dry_run:
        os.chdir(root_dir)

if base_dir is None:
    base_dir = os.curdir
...
```

The function saves the current working directory at the beginning of its execution and restores it before returning, but this is not enough for thread-safety.

Comment: Is there any thread safe alternative for shutil.make_archive?

Comment: @Andrey I posted an answer with a thread-safe alternative

Answer (score 2):

Here is my **thread-safe alternative** to `shutil.make_archive` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1855118/2111778):

```py
import zipfile
import os

def make_archive_threadsafe(zip_name: str, path: str):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                zip.write(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), path))

make_archive_threadsafe('/root/backup.zip', '/root/some_data/')
```

Note that `make_archive` also uses `ZipFile` internally so this should be solid.

This does not include the folder-to-zip into the zip ("single top-level folder") unlike the answer I linked -- personal preference.

Code is Python 3, but works in Python 2 if you remove type annotations.