# Create a Zip with 2 CSV on it

Tags: python, csv, pandas, zip

I am exporting 2 dataframes as csv, like these ones could be:

```
data1 = {'isin':['isin1','isin2','isin3'],'ticker_QF':['ticker1','ticker3','ticker3']}

df_QF = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'isin':['isin1','isin1','isin2','isin3'],'ticker_BBG':['ticker1','ticker3','ticker4','ticker5']}
df_BBG = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

If I want to create a zip foldier with both csv on it, how can I do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Write files to `dir_name` folder and then `shutil.make_archive(output_filename, 'zip', dir_name)`, then remove the `dir_name` if needed perhaps?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory/)

Comment: @ Kaveen Perera I've read it but I don't really understand it, maybe anybody had done my task before. I will keep working on it ot see if I get it better. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Python's `zipfile` library to help with this as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

data1 = {'isin':['isin1','isin2','isin3'],'ticker_QF':['ticker1','ticker3','ticker3']}
data2 = {'isin':['isin1','isin1','isin2','isin3'],'ticker_BBG':['ticker1','ticker3','ticker4','ticker5']}

with zipfile.ZipFile('my_csvs.zip', 'w') as csv_zip:
    csv_zip.writestr("data1.csv", pd.DataFrame(data1).to_csv())
    csv_zip.writestr("data2.csv", pd.DataFrame(data2).to_csv())
```

This would result in one zip file called `my_csvs.zip` containing two zip files. Also, the CSV file are created directly inside the ZIP file and no additional files are created.

Tested in Python 3.7.3

Comment: Well, that is just perfect.   @Martin Evans