# Create archive of a directory by first archiving all individual files in it (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, zip, shutil

I have a directory `dir` which contains 3 files: `f1.txt`, `f2.txt`, `f3.pngt`.

I want to create a **zip archive** *given the path of that directory* where **each file will be a zip archive**. The resulting `zipped_archive.zip` should be on the same path as the `dir` is.

That is, I want the `zipped_archive.zip` to contain `f1.zip`, `f2.zip`, `f3.zip` where each of these `f#.zip` files contains the correspondingly-named `txt` or `png` file.

The above is better illustrated with this *file-structure*:

```
tmp
 |
 +-- dir
 |    |
 |    +-- f1.txt
 |    +-- f2.txt
 |    +-- f3.txt
 |
 +-- zipped_archive.zip
 |          |
 |          +-- f1.zip
 |          |     |
 |          |     +-- f1.txt
 |          +-- f2.zip
 |          |     |
 |          |     +-- f2.txt
 |          +-- f3.zip
 |          |     |
 |          |     +-- f3.png
```

I have tried to apply `zipfile` as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1855118) and `shutil` as seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25650295), both from the same question. I though of using `shutil.make_archive` on each file and in the end do a `ziph.write` with that result but I struggle to make it work and got confused.

Can someone suggest/provide some example code to help me understand how this works?

Comment: If you provide the code you've already tried, it'll be much easier to examine the problem.

Comment: @SangbokLee True but I chose not too because I merely tried to combine the code from the 2 answers I mentioned exactly as I described and the behaviour/results is not helpful (I think).

Comment: @nk-fford It's still good practice to provide the code you've tried, along with a specific description of how it's behaving differently than you expect (including full stack trace if you're getting an Exception). Otherwise you're just asking for code, and that's not really what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: @glibdud You are right. I will try to add my rough code attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
import os
import zipfile

target = "dir"
os.chdir(target)  # change directory to target
files = os.listdir('.')  # get all filenames into a list

zipfiles = []  # a list which will be used later for containing zip files
for i in range(len(files)):
    fn = files[i].split('.')[0] + '.zip'  # f#.??? -> f#.zip
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(fn, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zipf.write(files[i])
    zipf.close()
    zipfiles.append(fn)  # put f#.zip into the list for later use

zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('../zipped_archive.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
for i in range(len(zipfiles)):
    zipf.write(zipfiles[i])
    os.remove(zipfiles[i])  # delete f#.zip after archiving

zipf.close()
os.chdir('..')  # change directory to target's parent
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Could you please add a short description (or comments) so that I can easier follow and understand your solution?

Comment: Okay I added some comments. If you still have difficulty in understanding, try running one line at one time and print its result in Python console.

Comment: Confused about your 10th line: why do you rename/add the `.zip` suffix at the end of each file? Should it not the next `ZipFile` command which does the compression actually add that suffix?

Comment: As far as I know, `zipfile` does not add an extension(`.zip`) automatically. As you can see in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects), you should provide a full filename.