# Download all files in a path on Jupyter notebook server with file restrictions of 250 MB

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

As I want to save some online assignments on my own from juypter notebook (they have a folder structure ) to save it on my local drive, I already find a useful post in here: [Download all files in a path on Jupyter notebook server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042793/download-all-files-in-a-path-on-jupyter-notebook-server). Where I figure out how to download the full folder or some smaller folder structures.

```
!tar chvfz notebook.tar.gz *
```

How can i use this formula to download files which are bigger then 250MB? This files I am not able to save on my local drive.

Note that i am creating an archive with this command, and afterwards I want to download it. How can I limit the archive in a logical way?? That I can still use the files afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the problem is Jupyter, your network, or your local machine...

It's not clear how your files are structured, but if you have multiple "assignments", you can create archives for each

```
!tar chvfz notebook1.tar.gz assignment1/*
!tar chvfz notebook2.tar.gz assignment2/*
```

If you end up having a single large file still, I feel like another option would be to use Dropbox Python SDK, for example, to upload files to some shared file server

Otherwise, you're equivalently asking the same thing as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61774/create-a-tar-archive-split-into-blocks-of-a-maximum-size