# Move exercise from Vocareum to a local PC running Anaconda Notebook

Tags: python, server, jupyter-notebook, download

This is the Vocareum screen from my class.

[image: Screen shot from Vocareum]

We are encouraged to download the project to a local instance of Anaconda Navigator Jupyter Notebook and work there.  I am attempting to determine how to do this.  I am running Windows 11 and the current version of Jupyter Notebook version `6.4.12`.  There is a respected response on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042793/download-all-files-in-a-path-on-jupyter-notebook-server) but I do not know if it applies to Windows and, if so, on what screen(s) to make the entries.

Answer (score 0):

The link to the Vocareum exercise is [here](https://labs.vocareum.com/main/main.php?m=editor&asnid=1125360&stepid=1125361&hideNavBar=1).  There does not seem to be a download control, though there is an upload button. I need all four folders:

1. `assets`
2. `data`
3. `resource`
4. `DirectMailAdvertising.ipynb`

I have been able some months ago to download the ipynb file without the assets, data, and resource files but, of course, that does not allow the exercise to run.  I did this by opening the notebook, going to `File/Download as/Notebook.ipynb`