# Python zip multiple directories into one zip file

Tags: python, zip, archive

I have a top directory `ds237` which has multiple sub-directories under it as below:

```
ds237/
├── dataset_description.json
├── derivatives
├── sub-01
├── sub-02
├── sub-03
├── sub-04
├── sub-05
├── sub-06
├── sub-07
├── sub-08
├── sub-09
├── sub-10
├── sub-11
├── sub-12
├── sub-13
├── sub-21
├── sub-22
├── sub-23
├── sub-24
├── sub-25
├── sub-26
├── sub-27
├── sub-28
├── sub-29
```

I am trying to create multiple zip files(with proper zip names) from ds237 as per size of the zip files. 
`sub01-01.zip: contain sub-01 to sub-07`
`sub08-13.zip : it contains sub08 to sub-13`

I have written a logic which creates a list of sub-directories `[sub-01,sub-02, sub-03, sub-04, sub-05]`. I have created the list so that the total size of the all subdirectories in the list should not be > 5gb.

***My question:*** is how can I write a function to zip these sub-dirs (which are in a list) into a destination zip file with a proper name.
Basically i want to write a function as follows:

`def zipit([list of subdirs], 'path/to/zipfile/sub*-*.zip'):`

I Linux I generally achieve this by:

```
'zip -r compress/sub01-08.zip ds237/sub-0[1-8]'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1855118/375530, you can re-use that answer's function to add a directory to a ZipFile.

```
import os
import zipfile


def zipdir(path, ziph):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file),
                       os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file),
                                       os.path.join(path, '..')))


def zipit(dir_list, zip_name):
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for dir in dir_list:
        zipdir(dir, zipf)
    zipf.close()
```

The `zipit` function should be called with your pre-chunked list and a given name. You can use string formatting if you want to use a programmatic name (e.g. `"path/to/zipfile/sub{}-{}.zip".format(start, end)`).

Comment: the above script will create a zip file by excluding the path of directory. 
Let say i zip `/Users/aba/ds100/sub-0[1-6]` into `sub01-06.zip` then when i uncompress the zip, it should generate following path `ds100/sub-01` and other directories.

Comment: You can also change the `relpath` to go two directories up from `path`. So change `os.path.join(path, '..')` to `os.path.join(path, '..', '..')` and it should work.

Comment: it does the job partially but when i uncompress the `sub01-06.zip` and `sub07-09.zip`, ideally it should uncompress into `ds100/sub-01  ds100/sub-02  ds100/sub-03  ds100/sub-04 ds100/sub-05 ds100/sub-06 ds100/sub-07 ds100/sub-08 ds100/sub-09,

However above script with chnages you suggested crates two different `ds100`

Comment: Not sure what you're seeing, I ran a similar test and was able to extract both zips to fill in the `ds100` directory. There may be some configuration with your unzip tool. You can also use `unzip zip_file.zip -d output_directory` to unzip the file `zip_file.zip` to `output_directory`. This would also be an alternate to changing the code to put `ds100` in there, where you would just specify the output directory as `ds100`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) calling 'zip' and passing the paths as arguments

Comment: I intend to do this in pythonic way

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you zip file with a first folder `ds100`:

```
import os
import zipfile    

def zipit(folders, zip_filename):
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    for folder in folders:
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder):
            for filename in filenames:
                zip_file.write(
                    os.path.join(dirpath, filename),
                    os.path.relpath(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), os.path.join(folders[0], '../..')))

    zip_file.close()


folders = [
    "/Users/aba/ds100/sub-01",
    "/Users/aba/ds100/sub-02",
    "/Users/aba/ds100/sub-03",
    "/Users/aba/ds100/sub-04",
    "/Users/aba/ds100/sub-05"]

zipit(folders, "/Users/aba/ds100/sub01-05.zip")
```

For example `sub01-05.zip` would have a structure similar to:

```
ds100
├── sub-01
|   ├── 1
|       ├── 2
|   ├── 1
|   ├── 2
├── sub-02
    ├── 1
        ├── 2
    ├── 1
    ├── 2
```

Answer (score 0):

To batch zip, improving from [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46267469/11671779), you can use the following

```py
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED

base_dir = "."
base_zip_dir = f"{base_dir}/zip"
target_dir = f"{base_dir}/data"
folders_per_zip = 500

os.makedirs(base_zip_dir, exist_ok=True)

def zipdir(path, ziph):
    for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file),
                       os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(path, '..')))

def batch_zip(folder_list, folders_per_zip, target_dir):
    for i, folders in enumerate(zip(*[iter(folder_list)] * folders_per_zip), start=1):
        zip_filename = f"{target_dir}/{i}.zip"
        with ZipFile(zip_filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
            for folder in folders:
                if any(os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, f)) for f in os.listdir(folder)):
                    zipdir(folder, zipf)
        print(f"Zip file {zip_filename} created.")

folders = [f.path for f in os.scandir(target_dir) if f.is_dir()]
batch_zip(folders , folders_per_zip, base_zip_dir)
```