# Zip directories from listed ones

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am relatively new to Python, I am trying to make a script which will only zip subfolders that I define in a list, with their content of course. I tried modifying various codes from Stack Overflow and whatever I found on internet but either I zip all subfolders, or I zip subfolders that I want but without content.

List could be full path to subfolder or can I define the path to the root folder and then specify subfolders?

This is the idea: 3 subfolders 1,2,3 and I want to zip only subfolders 1 and 3. I added the last code that I was modifying but I just can't return the list in a function.

```
Folder
|- SubFolder1
|  |- file1.txt
|  |- file2.txt
|- SubFolder2
|  |- file1.txt
|  |- file2.txt
|- SubFolder3
|  |- file1.txt
|  |- file2.txt
```

The code:

```
import os
import zipfile


list=["SubFolder1", "SubFolder3"]

def zipdir(path, ziph):

# ziph is zipfile handle
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file))


if __name__ == '__main__':

zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zipdir(**list**, zipf)
zipf.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code and think this way it should work as expected if I understand your request correctly. Please check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46267469/9152905) too, I think it's pretty much what you are looking for ;-)

1) os.walk goes through each of your subfolders, too. So just wait until each subfolder becomes the "root" (here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54790514/9152905)).

2) Check whether the folder is contained in the list. If it is, zip all files within this folder

3) Recreate the subfolder structure relative to your original root-folder

```
import os
import zipfile

rootpath = r'C:\path\to\your\rootfolder'
list=["SubFolder1", "SubFolder3"]

def zipdir(path, ziph, dirlist):
  # ziph is zipfile handle
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if os.path.basename(root) in dirlist:
      for file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        relative_path = os.path.relpath(file_path, path)
        ziph.write(file_path, relative_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
  zipdir(rootpath, zipf, list)
  zipf.close()
```