# How to zip the contents of a whole directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using python 2.7 and try to archive a directory:
the object is to: archive the whole folder's content
subject: C:\User\blah\blah\parentfolder

```
structure:C...parentfolder\ 1.docx
                            2.xlxs
                            4.pdf
                            subfolder\5.pdf
                                      6.txt
```

Now I know that shutil.make_archive() can zip me the folder, but it turned out to be like this

```
C:\\User\\blah\\blah\\zipfile_name\\parentfolder\ 1.docx
                                                  2.xlxs
                                                  4.pdf
                                                  subfolder\5.pdf
                                                            6.txt
```

**but I want a to skip the parentfolder layer in the zipfile_name folder, that is:**(This is where the problem is different, I did learn shutil.make_archive from that question, but as I open the shutil module, I found out that make_archive has four intakes. I didn't know what makes them different and used the four input one, that's where I had my question. The previous one didn't not point out why it used just three inputs, and the other answers were using very complicated self-defined functions or so. The answer I chose in this problem compared and explained the difference, which I really appreciate. As a non-computer science majored, I think this kind of details help a lot of people.)

```
C:\\User\\blah\\blah\\zipfile_name\\ 1.docx
                                     2.xlxs
                                     4.pdf
                                     subfolder\5.pdf
                                               6.txt
```

if I use os.path.walk and so on to write every file to zipfile_name, it seems it will be super complicated, as I will need to first 1.list everything in the folder--while:1 file?--write into zip folder while:0 directory?--make_directory , and list all items, and while loop again this process( do until no directory exists in the last directory)

Plus I don't know how to make a directory in a .zip folder.  So all this just seems complicated.

So is there a way to change a folder into an archive folder while keeping the folder structure?

Comment: Do the super complicated thing. That's what every normal zip utility does.

Comment: What if you just call `os.chdir('c:\\...\\parentfolder')` before you call `shutil.make_archive`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a zip archive of a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a matter of how you pass the information about the `parentfolder` folder in the parameters of `make_archive`.

Consider the following two examples:

```
shutil.make_archive('myarchive', 'zip', '/User/blah/blah', 'parentfolder')
```

This will create the zip archive myarchive.zip. If you open myarchive.zip you will first see the folder `parentfolder` and if you open that you will see the contents of the original `parentfolder` from which the archive was made.

```
shutil.make_archive('myarchive', 'zip', '/User/blah/blah/parentfolder')
```

This will create the zip archive myarchive.zip. If you open myarchive.zip you will immediately see the contents of the original `parentfolder` from which the archive was made. The folder name `parentfolder` will not appear in the archive.

The parameters are documented in https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html, though to be honest it is not easy for me to see where the behavior I illustrated above is documented. I found it by trial and error
(Python 2.7.14 on Windows).

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I didn't know this will change the output. I did give make_archive four parameters.I tried your suggestion and it worked perfectly.