# Zip list of files python

Tags: python, csv, zip

I have created some csv files in my code and I would like to zip them as one folder to be sent by e-mail. I already have the e-mail function but the problem is to zip. 
I tried to use this: [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) I am not extracting or find the files in a directory. I am creating the program the csv files and making a list of it. 
My list of files is like this:

```
lista_files = [12.csv,13.csv,14.csv]
```

It seems to be easy for developers but as a beginning it is hard. I would really appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a zip archive of a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `zipfile` library.  And given that you're looking at a list of filenames, I'd just iterate using a `for` loop.  If you have directories listed as well, you could use `os.walk`.

```
import zipfile

lista_files = ["12.csv","13.csv","14.csv"]
with zipfile.ZipFile('out.zip', 'w') as zipMe:        
    for file in lista_files:
        zipMe.write(file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```