# How to copy the entire file into a zip file

Tags: python, zip

I want to put a file in every file of .txt, .mp3, and mp4 files.

```
import zipfile
import os
path = "G:"
file_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(path+'\\archive.zip', 'w')
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.jpg,.txt,.mp3,.mp4'):
            file_zip.write(os.path.join(folder, file), os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder,file), path), compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

file_zip.close()
```

When I open the zip file, the zip file is empty!

Comment: I hope you gave this a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
if file.endswith('.jpg,.txt,.mp3,.mp4'):
```

to:

```
if file.endswith(('.jpg', '.txt', '.mp3', '.mp4')):
```