# compress with python but file is empty?

Tags: python, zip, compression

I'm trying to compress a folder with all files inside it
but I get the compressed file empty 
Im using this code

```
import os
import zipfile

def zipdir(path, ziph):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zipdir('tmp/', zipf)
    zipf.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a zip archive of a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory)

Comment: Strange. Your code works on my machine.

Comment: Im using windows 7 and don't know why i get an empty zip file

Comment: I believe the problem is you're sending a relative path, try using the absolute path.