# How to generate zip folder for multiple output in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, data-science

i am trying to build an application .Its working fine to genrate csv and pdf file .Now i want to generate an zip file which will contain both pdf and csv output how to do that?

my code:

```
def save_analysis():
    file = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".csv", filetypes=[('CSV Files','*.csv')])
    print(file.name, "save file name")
    predict.generateCSV(adf,file.name)
    root.update()
    messagebox.showinfo("Saved Analysis", "Successfully Generated and Saved File to :\n" + file.name)

def view_stats():
    file = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".pdf", filetypes=[('Pdf Files','*.pdf')])
    print(file.name, "save file name")
    visual.show_visuals(adf,file.name)
    root.update()
    messagebox.showinfo("Visualization Saved", "Successfully Generated and Saved File to :\n" + file.name)
```

Comment: Assuming you create both files in the same directory, how this question does not have your needs? : https://stackoverflow.com/q/1855095/4636715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to zip both pdf and csv as single zip file, you can use [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) or shutil libraires.

Copy the files you want to zip under a folder and then use this code

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive(output_filename, 'zip', folder_path)
```

For Zipfile, check this  [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-zip-files-python/) .