# Create zip from directory using Python

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to use Python to create a zip-file from a directory. I have looked at [How to create a zip archive of a directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory-in-python) and it works but I have another problem. So I have this:

```
MyDir
|- DirToZip
|  |- SubDir1
|  |  |- file1.txt
|  |  |- file2.txt
|  |- SubDir2
|  |  |- file3.txt
|  |  |- file4.txt
|  |- basefile.txt
|  |- mimetype
|- create_zip.py
```

This is my `create_zip.py` so far:

```
import os, zipfile

name = 'DirToZip'
zip_name = name + '.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_ref:
    for folder_name, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(name):
        for filename in filenames:
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
            zip_ref.write(file_path)

zip_ref.close()
```

As I said, this works ok as far as the code goes, but the problem is that the zip-file is not created as I want to have it. Now it has the root folder `DirToZip` as only folder in the file root and the other files inside that folder. But I would lite to not have that root folder and only have the sub folders in the zip file.

**WRONG (what I don't want):**

```
DirToZip.zip
|- DirToZip
|  |- SubDir1
|  |  |- file1.txt
|  |  |- file2.txt
|  |- SubDir2
|  |  |- file3.txt
|  |  |- file4.txt
|  |- basefile.txt
|  |- mimetype
```

**CORRECT (what I want):**

```
DirToZip.zip
|- SubDir1
|  |- file1.txt
|  |- file2.txt
|- SubDir2
|  |- file3.txt
|  |- file4.txt
|- basefile.txt
|- mimetype
```

I tried adding `for file in os.listdir(name):` after `with zipfile...` and change to `... in os.walk(file)` but that did not work. The zip file became empty instead.

What can I do?

Comment: ```zip_ref.write(filename)``` - method has additional parameter arcname, you can just change it from defaulting to filename as you like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple as that:

```
import os, zipfile

name = 'DirToZip'
zip_name = name + '.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_ref:
    for folder_name, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(name):
        for filename in filenames:
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
            zip_ref.write(file_path, arcname=os.path.relpath(file_path, name))

zip_ref.close()
```