# How to compress folders using zipfile?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-zipfile

My program so far is successfully able to add and compress files which are present in the same directory as `test.py` but there is also a folder named `location` in the same directory which contains additional files say `citynames.txt` What happens is when I do a simple zip.write (The logic used in `else` block) `location` is added to the zip file however its empty that is it does not contain `citynames.txt` inside it for some reason please help me add the folder itself somehow?

```
import os
import zipfile
import shutil
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))  #holds the directory where script is located
os.chdir(dir_path)                                      #Changes to directory where script is located
fp=os.listdir(dir_path)                                 #file pointer

directory_size=len(os.listdir(dir_path))

zip1=zipfile.ZipFile('Archive.zip','w')

for i in range(directory_size) :
   if fp[i]=='test.py':
      break
   if fp[i]=='location':
      #Some code needs to be added here to write all the contents of folder "location" into 
       "Archive.zip"

   else:
       zip1.write(fp[i],compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

print("Process completed")
```

Assuming location has further sub-folders how to zip the files inside them aswell?

Comment: You have the code, make a backup, so you can recover, and try running it.

Comment: yeah i did.. Thanks !! also it still doesn't give me `locations` sub folders or its content been trying all day :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: zipfile - Work with ZIP archives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile).

The (main) problem in your code is that you're mistaking *continue* by *break*. That way, when *test.py* is encountered, all the items after it will be ignored, as *break* exits the loop.

Here's a variant that recurses into subdirectories using [[Python 3.Docs]: glob.**iglob**(*pathname, *, recursive=False*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) and adds files in the archive.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import glob
import zipfile


def main(*argv):
    archive_name = "archive.zip"
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    dir_path_len = len(dir_path) + len(os.path.sep)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(archive_name, mode="w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
        for file_name in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir_path, "**"), recursive=True):
            if os.path.isdir(file_name):
                continue
            member_name = file_name[dir_path_len:]
            if member_name in [
                os.path.basename(__file__),
                archive_name,
            ]:
                continue
            print(member_name)
            zf.write(file_name, member_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059933596>tree /f /a
> Folder PATH listing for volume SSD0-WORK
> Volume serial number is AE9E-72AC
> E:.
> |   code00.py
> |   file0.txt
> |
> \---locations
>     |   location0.tzt
>     |   location1.txt
>     |
>     \---subdir0
>             subdir0file0.txt
>
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059933596>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> file0.txt
> locations\location0.tzt
> locations\location1.txt
> locations\subdir0\subdir0file0.txt
>
> Done.
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059933596>dir *.zip
>  Volume in drive E is SSD0-WORK
>  Volume Serial Number is AE9E-72AC
>
>  Directory of e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059933596
>
> 20/01/27  20:13               547 archive.zip
>                1 File(s)            547 bytes
>                0 Dir(s)  113,094,475,776 bytes free
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add each file in *location* on it's own to `zip1`.
Add this to the according `if`-branch:

```py
for f in os.listdir("location"):
    zip1.write("location/"+f, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not able to add a directory to the zip archive is because `zip1.write` is not recursive (It won't add files that are further down the directory tree, only what you explicitly tell it to add). You'll need to use `os.walk` to go through all sub-directories and add each file individually:

```
import os
import zipfile


def zipdir(dir_to_archive, archive_filename):
    ziph = zipfile.ZipFile(archive_filename, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_to_archive):
        for file in files:
            if file != archive_filename:
                ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file))
    ziph.close()


os.chdir(dir_path)
zipdir(dir_path, 'Archive.zip')
```

Note, the above code was adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1855118/7681119) answer by [Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers).