# Is password protected zip different from encrypted zip file?

Tags: windows, encryption, zip

I have created an encrypted zip file using python. When i try to extract it in windows using Extract All option, windows is showing error. But it works when i use Right click-> Unzip(Encrypted)

But i have other password protected zip files which will ask for the password when i use extract all option.

Is encrypted zip differ from password protected zip? Is it possible to create the encrypted zip so that i can extract it normally in windows? (Extract All->Provide password)

Comment: Can you share some code showing how you created the encrypted zip file?

Comment: Sure. I have posted it in another question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087965/how-to-zip-a-folder-in-python-with-password/60088284?noredirect=1#comment106273769_60088284