# How to zip all sub folders and their files into a single zip file of a directory

Tags: python, recursion, zip, subdirectory

I have code that zips all files inside a directory but ignores subfolders.
I would like to include subfolders and their files recurvisely.

I have tried changing the for from "for f in files" to "for f in dirs" but I ended up zipping empty folders and not the files.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

````
# Creates the zip on the current directory for the given folder and moves them to a target directory
# Input parameter "directory": The directory that contains the files to be zipped
# Input parameter "age": Only zip files older than this age.
# Input parameter "targetdir": Move zip file created into the target directory
# Return: Zipfilename: The zip file that was created
# Return: Count: Number of files zipped or zero if no files were zipped
def makeZipMove(directory, age, targetdir):
    
    os.chdir(directory)

    now = datetime.now()
    milis = str(datetime.now())[24:]

    fileprefix = now.strftime("Archive_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_"+milis)
    zipfilename = fileprefix + '.zip'
    
    delta = time.time() - (float(age) * 86400)

    UniversalZipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    count = 0

    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
        for f in files:
            try:
                if os.stat(f).st_mtime < delta :
                    if not f.endswith(parser.get('defaults', 'default_dont_consider_for_zipping')):
                        UniversalZipfile.write(f)
                        os.remove(f)
                        logging.info("Zipping: " + f)
                        count = count+1

                            
            except PermissionError as ex:
                logging.warning(ex);
                logging.warning("This will not prevent the zipping. Please clear or ignore this file")
            except:
                logging.error("Unexpected error occured")
                logging.fatal(traceback.format_exc())
        break
        
    if count!=0:

        if not f.endswith(parser.get('defaults', 'default_dont_consider_for_zipping')):
            UniversalZipfile.close()
            shutil.move(zipfilename, targetdir)
        
    # Remove the zipfile again if it has zero files.
    if count == 0:
        UniversalZipfile.close()
        os.remove(zipfilename)
        
    return zipfilename, count    ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a zip archive of a directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory-in-python)

Comment: You just need to make the edit `zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))`