# Zipping files to the same folder level

Tags: python, shutil

This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory-in-python) advises to use `shutil`to zip files:

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive(output_filename, 'zip', dir_name)
```

This zips everything in `dir_name` and maintains the folder structure in it. Is it possible to use this same library to remove all sub-folders and just zip all files in `dir_name` into the same level? Or must I introduce a separate code chunk to first consolidate the files?  For eg., this is a hypothetical folder structure:

```
\dir_name
   \dir1
       \cat1
          file1.txt
          file2.txt
       \cat2
          file3.txt
   \dir2
       \cat3
          file4.txt
```

Output zip should just contain:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shutil.make_archive` does not have a way to do what you want without copying files to another directory, which is inefficient.  Instead you can use a compression library directly similar to the linked answer you provided.  Note this doesn't handle name collisions!

```py
import zipfile
import os

with zipfile.ZipFile('output.zip','w',zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,compresslevel=9) as z:
    for path,dirs,files in os.walk('dir_name'):
        for file in files:
            full = os.path.join(path,file)
            z.write(full,file) # write the file, but with just the file's name not full path

# print the files in the zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile('output.zip') as z:
    for name in z.namelist():
        print(name)
```

Given:

```
dir_name
├───dir1
│   ├───cat1
│   │       file1.txt
│   │       file2.txt
│   │
│   └───cat2
│           file3.txt
│
└───dir2
    └───cat3
            file4.txt
```

Output:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
```

Comment: @Tristan: From what I read, another advantage of not using `shutil.make_archive`—besides not needing to copy files to another directory first—is that using the `zipfile` module directly will actually compress the data of files in the archive, potentially making the resulting archive much smaller depending on what's in the files.

Comment: Thanks for the code and advice. I think this would work for after reading around further.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# The root directory to search for
path = r'dir_name/'

import os
import glob

# List all *.txt files in the root directory
file_paths = [file_path 
              for root_path, _, _ in os.walk(path) 
              for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(root_path, '*.txt'))]

import tempfile

# Create a temporary directory to copy your files into
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp:
    import shutil

    for file_path in file_paths:
        # Get the basename of the file
        basename = os.path.basename(file_path)

        # Copy the file to the temporary directory  
        shutil.copyfile(file_path, os.path.join(tmp, basename))

    # Zip the temporary directory to the working directory
    shutil.make_archive('output', 'zip', tmp)
```

This will create a *output.zip* file in the current working directory. The temporary directory will be deleted when the end of the context manager is reached.

Comment: Thanks. This was somewhat I was thinking of if shutil cannot flatten the directory directly. This works. But @Mark Tolonen's solution seems a little more robust. I like both solutions, to be honest.