# zip the files in a given directory into same directory python

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

I am working in a directory with path being "C:\Downloads\Project" I have a folder "Insights" in "Project" (Project\Insights) folder which has multiple text files with names being "Text1.txt", "Text2.txt"..."Text30.txt". Every 10 text files are supposed to be zipped into a zip file into same "Insights" folder (...\Insights\zip1.zip).

How can this be done in Python?

When I tried zipping, text files are being stored with directory structure "...\Project\Insights\text1.txt" in zip file. But I don't want the files to be stored with any directory structure.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

#dictionary of files and data in it (dummy data)
file_data={"C:\Downloads\Project\Insights\Text1.txt":"value1", 
            "C:\Downloads\Project\Insights\Text2.txt":"value2"
          }

zipp = ZipFile('Insights//zip1.zip', 'w')
for k, v in file_data.items():
    zipp.write(k)
zipp.close()
```

This snippet generates zip file with entire directory structure. But I want the text files alone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a zip archive of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory)

Comment: @keerthi pls add your code snippets here in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Ananth.P, I have attached the snippet I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this snippet:

```
import os
import zipfile
    
def zipdir(path, ziph):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file), 
                       os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), 
                                       os.path.join(path, '..')))
      
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zipdir('tmp/', zipf)
zipf.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, this one worked after making minor changes in os.path.relpath() in
ziph.write() function