# Python - create zip file

Tags: python, zip

I'm running python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu and I wish to create a zip file (based on 2 files).

I'm running pip3 install ZipFile and I'm getting the following error

```
> Collecting ZipFile   Could not find a version that satisfies the
> requirement ZipFile (from versions: ) No matching distribution found
> for ZipFile
```

If i can not update my python version - which module I can use ?

Comment: Why do you think you need to install anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a zip archive of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html) is included in the python standard library, you don't have to install it.