# Better way to zip files in Python (zip a whole directory with a single command)?

Tags: python, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I zip the contents of a folder using python (version 2.5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296499/how-do-i-zip-the-contents-of-a-folder-using-python-version-2-5)

Suppose I have a directory: `/home/user/files/`. This dir has a bunch of files:

```
/home/user/files/
  -- test.py
  -- config.py
```

I want to zip this directory using `ZipFile` in python. Do I need to [loop through the directory and add these files recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458436/adding-folders-to-a-zip-file-using-python), or is it possible do pass the directory name and the ZipFile class automatically adds everything beneath it?

In the end, I would like to have:

```
/home/user/files.zip (and inside my zip, I dont need to have a /files folder inside the zip:)
  -- test.py
  -- config.py
```

Comment: Since os.walk yields the entire content of the directory -- doing the recursion for you -- it seems like a trivial loop.  What are you trying to optimize?  Lines of code?  I don't see how.  Time?  Not possible -- Zip takes the time it takes.  What problem are you having?

Comment: I just want to zip a folder that may have empty folders, without coding a bunch of lines for something that my Linux machine can do with a single command using the zip utility and the subprocess module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess

PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
pd = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/zip', '-r', 'files', 'files'],
                      stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = pd.communicate()
```

The code is not tested and pretends to works just on unix machines, i don't know if windows has similar command line utilities.

Comment: I'm already using subprocess in another section of my script, this is what I was looking for! I didn't think about using zip from *nixes machines, thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Note that this doesn't include empty directories.  If those are required there are workarounds available on the web; probably best to get the ZipInfo record for empty directories in our favorite archiving programs to see what's in them.

Hardcoding file/path to get rid of specifics of my code...

```
target_dir = '/tmp/zip_me_up'
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/example.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
rootlen = len(target_dir) + 1
for base, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
   for file in files:
      fn = os.path.join(base, file)
      zip.write(fn, fn[rootlen:])
```

Comment: In python 3 the `pathlib` module makes this much easier, Use `Path(<your_path>).rglob('*')` like this to add all your files to a ZipFile object:

`for _file in Path(path).rglob('*'):            zip.write(str(_file))`

Answer (score 7):

You could try using the distutils package:

```
distutils.archive_util.make_zipfile(base_name, base_dir[, verbose=0, dry_run=0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also be able to get away with using the [`zip`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_zip.htm) command available in the Unix shell with a call to [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system)