# Python add file to zip by giving filepath?

Tags: python, zip

I have a similar problem to a question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612094/better-way-to-zip-files-in-python-zip-a-whole-directory-with-a-single-command) with the following code:

```
import zipfile

report_zip = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\report.zip"
report = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\report.json"

json_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(report_zip, "w")
try:
    json_zip.write(report)
finally:
    json_zip.close()
```

The result of the code is as such:

```
report.zip
 --Users
   --user
     --Desktop
       --report.json
```

Whereas what I want is:

```
report.zip
 --report.json
```

How should I modify my current implementation to achieve this? Or is there a better implementation? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `arcname` parameter to `ZipFile.write()`.

Comment: Doesn't work, the directories are still inside the zipped file

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write): `Write the file named filename to the archive, giving it the archive name arcname (by default, this will be the same as filename, but without a drive letter and with leading path separators removed).`