# Python - on windows, how to make all the files as zip?

Tags: python, windows

I have a folder `(C:\\Python27\\security_camera_snapshot\\)` where `image1.png 2.png 3.png .... 100.png` is stored. I need to make them in one.zip file and upload it to a NAS server.

But how can i do the compression of all those files in zip?

Comment: With the [zipfile module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html)?

Comment: would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296499/how-do-i-zip-the-contents-of-a-folder-using-python-version-2-5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a zip archive of a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the zipfile library as in this example adapted for your usage :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import zipfile

def zipdir(path, ziph):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('One.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zipdir('C:\\Python27\\security_camera_snapshot\\', zipf)
    zipf.close()
```