# Installing zlib on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

I use python to automate boring stuff I do daily (I'm not really a "programmer").
I've been building a script to compress my files to a zip folder. For that, I'm using `zipfile` library, but it only creates a ZIP file without compressing them.
In order to do that, they recommend to install zlib module and use the `ZIP_DEFLATED` flag.

I'm having hard time to install the static library of zlib. I found that on git hub.

> Assuming you have a functional zlib library installed in `c:\lib\zlib`
> (Download from https://zlib.net , use cmake to generate VS solution
> (with `param -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:\lib\zlib`), then build the
> `INSTALL` project from that solution, using Release mode settings)

But I don't know how to proceed with these instructions. Some one could translate to a lay guy how to install this library  on windows?

Thank in advance!

Comment: 1. you should be using Python 3 as Python 2.x is deprecated, 2. just use the built-in `zipfile`, example of how to create compressed archive files here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38550416/42346

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as said by @mechanical_meat is to use Python 3 instead, because Python 2.x is deprecated,

Note: just use the built-in zipfile, example of how to create compressed archive files here: stackoverflow.com/a/38550416/42346 –